# Change the colors of multiple polylines by OnPolylineClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, onclicklistener, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I have multiple polylines in google map. It has to change its color to blue when user click on each polyline and others should be grey.

I have added polylines to a list as follows...

```
polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();

polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOption1));
polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOption2));
polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOption3));
```

By using OnPolylineClickListener i tried to handle each polylines, but couldn`t able to do that..

```
mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline)
        {

        }
    });
```

Is my method correct? Can anyone one help to do this task?

Comment: What did you do in onPolylineClick method?

Comment: @ZiyaERKOC I tried to change the color of polyline to blue when i click it.By using  `polyline.setcolor(Color.BLUE);`. But, the 3rd polyline is on top of other polylines. So, other polyline colors hide under it. I need to display the selected polyline on top.(Like in google maps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Polyline.setZindex()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#setZIndex(float)) for do that: set Z-index for example to `1f` for non-clicked polylines and set Z-index grater than `1f` (e.g. `2f`) for clicked. Something like that:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
        // set settings (color, z-index) for all polylines
        polyline1.setColor(Color.RED);
        polyline1.setZIndex(1f);

        polyline2.setColor(Color.RED);
        polyline2.setZIndex(1f);

        polyline3.setColor(Color.RED);
        polyline3.setZIndex(1f);

        // set settings (color, z-index) for CLICKED polyline
        polyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        polyline.setZIndex(2f);
    }
});
```

where `polyline1`, `polyline2` and `polyline3` is:

```
final List<LatLng> poly1Points = new ArrayList<>();
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.27801,149.12958));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28032,149.12907));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28099,149.12929));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28144,149.12984));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28194,149.13003));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28282,149.12956));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28302,149.12881));
poly1Points.add(new LatLng(-35.28473,149.12836));

PolylineOptions polylineOptions1 = new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(poly1Points)
        .color(Color.RED)
        .width(20);

final List<LatLng> poly2Points = new ArrayList<>();
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.279472, 149.124717));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.280146, 149.125908));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.280453, 149.126380));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.281775, 149.125286));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.284245, 149.126649));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.284604, 149.129814));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.283395, 149.131209));
poly2Points.add(new LatLng(-35.285576, 149.134964));

PolylineOptions polylineOptions2 = new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(poly2Points)
        .color(Color.RED)
        .width(20);

final List<LatLng> poly3Points = new ArrayList<>();
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.284211, 149.123073));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.283624, 149.124586));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.281750, 149.123610));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.278711, 149.126163));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.278107, 149.126345));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.278536, 149.130626));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.278737, 149.131484));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.279516, 149.132031));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.281478, 149.133179));
poly3Points.add(new LatLng(-35.281478, 149.133179));

PolylineOptions polylineOptions3 = new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(poly3Points)
        .color(Color.RED)
        .width(20);

final Polyline polyline1 = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions1);
polyline1.setClickable(true);

final Polyline polyline2 = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions2);
polyline2.setClickable(true);

final Polyline polyline3 = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions3);
polyline3.setClickable(true);
```

And don't forget to `.setClickable(true)` for all polylines. As a result you should get something like that (clicked polyline is blue and on top):

[image: Clicked polyline]

Comment: It is working..!! Using setZIndex() for polylines is the best way to solve this. You have described it very well. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Andrri Omelchenko I need to clear one more doubt. How can i contact you. Can you please give  your email?

Comment: @AngathanNesarasa Just ask questions here.

Comment: After selecting each polylines, I need to display only tourist attraction near the selected polyline using markers in the google map. Can you help in this?

Comment: @AngathanNesarasa There is no "one step" solution for this task. Possible approach can be like that: from first to last node of selected polyline you should search nearby tourist attraction like in [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-search-nearby-displaying-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-google-maps-api-v2/) tutorial. Then for each founded attraction you should check it's distance to polyline segment for more precisely result . Also, probably, you should do that for points between polyline nodes. So, try and ask questions. I'm or someone else helps you.

Comment: Sure sir. I ll try it out. Thank you so much..!!

Comment: @AngathanNesarasa Good luck! I believe that you will succeed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173355/discussion-between-angathan-nesarasa-and-andrii-omelchenko).